# HTML PHP show form submit results on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a set of webpages that will display a unique graph based on a simple form that only has a selector box and a submit button. Basically what I want to happen is when the user changes the month in the selector and presses submit, a new chart set will render on the same page.

Here is the HTML initial page:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <SCRIPT src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <CENTER>
        <FORM ID="form1" METHOD="post" ACTION="">
            <SELECT NAME="monthSelector">
                <OPTION VALUE="0">Select Month...</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="1">January</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="2">February</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="3">March</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="4">April</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="5">May</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="6">June</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="7">July</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="8">August</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="9">September</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="10">October</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="11">November</OPTION>
                <OPTION VALUE="12">December</OPTION>
            </SELECT>
            <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Show Charts">
        </FORM>

        <DIV ID="response"></div>

        <SCRIPT>
            function submit()
            {
                $(function()
                {
                    var month = 3;
                    var formdata = "month=" + month;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'showCharts.php',
                        data: formdata,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#response").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        </SCRIPT>
    </CENTER>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and here is showCharts.php:

```
<?php
    include("../FusionCharts/FusionCharts.php");
    include("../DBConnect.php");

    $month = $_POST['month'];
    echo $month;
    //insert complex queries and fusioncharts code that already works!
?>
```

Someone please help me, I've been staring at this for hours and can't make any progress.

Comment: You're using `NAME="monthSelector"` and `$_POST['month']` try changing it to `NAME="month"` that ought to fix it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that's because he statically sets month=3 in the ajax.. what I don't get is what would make the `submit` function run when the form is submitted..

Comment: I always get mixed up with Ajax stuff. But when I see a (named) POST variable that doesn't match, it makes me raise a brow. @mishu

Comment: You'd need to define onsubmit="submit()"

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the .load method of jQuery:

```
function submit()
        {
             var month = 3;
             var formdata = month;
             $('#response').load('showCharts.php?month='+formdata);
        }
```

Also, you will need to set:

```
$month = $_REQUEST['month'];
```

Comment: The `URL` expands to `showCharts.php?month=month=3`

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be:

```
$('select').change(function() {
          var formdata = { month: document.getElementsByName('monthSelector')[0].value };
          $('#response').load( 'showCharts.php', formdata);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
<FORM ID="form1" METHOD="post" ACTION="">
```

for

```
<FORM ID="form1" METHOD="post" ONSUBMIT="submit(); return false;">
```

It should work.

In the part of jQuery, put this:

```
function submit()
{
    var month = $('select[name="monthSelector"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'showCharts.php',
        data:{'month':month},
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#response").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

One more thing: try to improve the HTML code, it will give a better image to your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the submit function is even called? Do you bind the form's submit event at all?

I would do something like `$("#form1").submit(submit);`

Also, you should return false at the end of submit() to block the default form action (which is refresh the current page I believe)

Comment: I see it, but it is, like you said, within the function. What calls the function in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the variable formdata to make it a json object rather than a string.

```
<SCRIPT>
            function submit()
            {
                $(function()
                {
                    var month = 3;
                    var formdata = {'month': month}; //change made here
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'showCharts.php',
                        data: formdata,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $("#response").html(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` will convert the object back to a query string anyway before making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery code should be as follows:

```
$(function() {
      var month = 3;
      var formdata = { month: month };
      $('#response').load( 'showCharts.php', formdata );

      $('#form1').submit(function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var formData = { month: this.monthSelector.value };
          $('#response').load( 'showCharts.php', formData);
      });
});
```

When using the ajax `.load()` method, here is what you should be aware of:

> **Request Method**
>
> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

Therefore, with the above jQuery code, your `PHP` script need not be changed.